# can i delete all data in table search_index of mediawiki platform?

Tags: mediawiki

I built a wiki made with mediawiki platform, 
I would like to delete datas in the wiki_search_index table for space reason.
I can delete the datas without troubles? Can i continue to use my mediawiki with no side effects?

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course [full text search won't work](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Searchindex_table), but nothing irrecoverable will happen: you can always [rebuild the table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Rebuildtextindex.php).

You should probably disable the feature properly rather than use the hammer on the database:

```
$wgDisableTextSearch = false;
```